# Can't make a POST request to REST API

Tags: visual-studio, azure, http-post, azure-web-app-service

GET, PUT, DELETE request work fine, but everytime i make a POST request I get an 500 status code. I have no idea where to start debuggin or what to look for. My api is depolyed on Microsoft Azure.

Any tips on what to look for or how to solve this issue would be much appriciated. I know a 500 status code, could be pretty much anything, but i find it really wierd that POST is the only request that dosn't work.

Comment: Do you have any sample code for your post request that you can share?

Comment: It would be nice if we had a sample code of your post request/post method. Anyway, you can debug your API with remote debugging on Azure, this will allow you to put breakpoint an see what happens in realtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no idea where to start debuggin or what to look for. My api is depolyed on Microsoft Azure.

Please make sure your API application could run fine locally before you deploy it to Azure. Besides, http 500 error indicates the server encountered an unexpected condition, if you deploy your app to Azure app service, you could [remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) to troubleshoot the issue. If you publish it as cloud service Web role, you could try to [use Azure compute emulator to debug your cloud service on a local machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-debugging-cloud-services-overview#debugging-an-azure-cloud-service-in-visual-studio).